# Can I load an XPage from another Db using the Include Page control?

Tags: xpages

Looking at xp:include control; we have the following syntax:

> <
>   xp:include pageName="/main.xsp" id="include1">

Is there any way to compute the pageName property so it makes reference to another Db?

[Designer Help](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_controls_cref_include.html?lang=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Can you?" Yes, but it's quite complicated and I wouldn't recommend attempting it. You would have to write an extended version of the Include control that could point to a different NSF and could include that NSF as a ModuleClassLoader for your current application. While this is theoretically possible, it requires a great deal of knowledge of the internal Java workings of XPages and a willingness to test extensively.

There may be other ways to solve your problem, such as using Design inheritance to include your target page in the local application. Otherwise, you're asking a question about what's possible with a sequence of ones and zeros, so of course the answer is "yes, but..."  And in this case, unless you have a desire to research the inner workings of the XSP server, or want to recruit someone who already has such knowledge, the answer to "Can *I*" is no.

Comment: What Nathan means: for normal mortals the answer is NO

Answer (score 1):

As Nathan says - the reality is that no you can't do that.  BUT you should think of WHY you're trying to do this?

Keep in mind that by not having your XPage source in the same place you won't have any kind of shared application or sessionScope available. Because of that it really is just like including a foreign web page and has nothing to do with XPages.

You'll probably be better off just using an iFrame if you want to run a foreign page inside another xpages application.